# Google doc: how to manage list item?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to develop a script to manage my own list with specific glyph.
So i have developped the following script (an extract) to do it.
It take the selection and transform a paragraph into a list.

But the behavior is random and strange:

- Even if i use the set glyph function, i get number
- I try to use the listID but it does not work correctly
- I set a emoticon as the glyph, get the listid manually outside this script but when i reapply it i lost everything

What am i doing wrongly?

```
var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
var body = doc.getBody();
var paragraphe, ParagrapheIndex, Text;  
var selectionRange = doc.getSelection() ? doc.getSelection().getRangeElements() : null;

var style_T1 = {}; //https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/attribute?hl=en
style_T1[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.LEFT;
style_T1[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Arial';
style_T1[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 12;
style_T1[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;
style_T1[DocumentApp.Attribute.SPACING_AFTER] = 4;
style_T1[DocumentApp.Attribute.SPACING_BEFORE] = 24;
style_T1[DocumentApp.Attribute.INDENT_FIRST_LINE] = 0;
style_T1[DocumentApp.Attribute.INDENT_START] = 30;
style_T1[DocumentApp.Attribute.LINE_SPACING] = 1;  
style_T1[DocumentApp.Attribute.UNDERLINE] = false; 


paragraphe = selectionRange[0].getElement();
Text = paragraphe.getText();
ParagrapheIndex = body.getChildIndex(paragraphe);
body.removeChild(paragraphe);
paragraphe = body.insertListItem(ParagrapheIndex,Text); 
paragraphe.setListId(kix.kcly1amq5g58);
paragraphe.setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.SQUARE_BULLET);
paragraphe.setNestingLevel(0);       
paragraphe.setAttributes(style_T1);
```

Thank you for your support
Rman

Comment: Could you provide a sample doc and the desired output?

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your return. I can not send you the link as it is company protected. Nevertheless you can copy paste the script above in a function, select a paragraph in a google doc and apply the script. I'm expecting to have something like:o fffff but instead i get 1 ffff. And in addition i would like to be able to apply some emotico glyph but i don't know if it is feasible